# How do I make a secure API request from an Arduino ESP32, programmed in the Arduino IDE using ArduinoJson?

Tags: json, api, curl, https, arduino

I have been hacking away at this for a few days with no luck.

I am trying to make a secure (SSL/HTTPS) API request in an Arduino environment. The controller I am using is an ESP32, which connects through wifi fine, and can retrieve/post data. However I am having no luck connecting to a secure API.

I'm trying to connect to this API https://strike.acinq.co/documentation/api-reference

EXAMPLE CURL REQUEST IN API'S DOCUMENTATION:

```
$ curl https://api.dev.strike.acinq.co/api/v1/charges \
   -u sk_pJDwxFxCVw5fQJhRRMpf29jReUjjN: \
   -X POST \
   -d amount=42000 \
   -d currency="btc" \
   -d description="1%20Blockaccino"
```

[image: ref]
[image: ref]

Here is my Arduino code, I am using the ArduinoJson.h and WiFi.h libraries:

```
// Connect to HTTP server
WiFiClient client;
client.setTimeout(10000);
if (!client.connect("api.strike.acinq.co", 80)) {
  Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));
return;
}

Serial.println(F("Connected!"));
// Send HTTP request
client.println(F("GET /api/v1/charges?id=MYKEY&amount=4200&currency=btc HTTP/1.0"));
client.println(F("Host: api.strike.acinq.co"));
client.println(F("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
client.println(F("Connection: close"));
if (client.println() == 0) {
   Serial.println(F("Failed to send request"));
return;
}

// Check HTTP status
char status[32] = {0};
client.readBytesUntil('\r', status, sizeof(status));
if (strcmp(status, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") != 0) {
  Serial.print(F("Unexpected response: "));
  Serial.println(status);
return;
}
```

A 401 "Invalid API Key" Is the closest I have got. I know the API-key works, and that I am just using it wrong. I've tried moving the key to:

```
 client.println(F("id: MYKEY"));
```

but that didn't work either.

I have tried other libraries and ArduinoJson seems to be the best. I think the issue is the fact its a secure server and the layout of my request. I found many resources for connecting to open API's on Arduino, but nothing on connecting to secure ones. I think I am almost there with the code...

**UPDATE**

So I have updated my code. I am still trying to use ArduinoJson. I can connect to the API but it keeps spitting out "HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST". I don't know weather this is because its over HTTPS or the formatting of my request.

In the API docs -u and -X don't have a field name like "amount=4200", so I am assuming -u would just be added `client.print("?="+apiKey);`

```
//open weather map api key 
String apiKey= "myapikey"; 

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS; 
char server[] = "api.strike.acinq.co";    



Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server..."); 
// if you get a connection, report back via serial: 
if (client.connect(server, 80)) { 
  Serial.println("connected to server"); 
  // Make a HTTP request: 
  client.print("POST /api/v1/charges"); 
  client.print("?="+apiKey); 
  client.print("&amount=4200"); 
  client.print("&currency='btc'"); 
  client.println("&description='sweets'"); 
  client.println("Host: api.strike.acinq.co"); 
  client.println("Connection: close"); 
  client.println(); 
} 
else { 
  Serial.println("unable to connect"); 
}
```

**UPDATE**

I figured out the println and print actually mean something and have subsequently organised my request much better. It still comes back with 400 Unauthorized?

```
String PostData = "&description=\"car\"&amount=1000&currency=\"sweetsandthat\"";

client.println("POST /api/v1/charges HTTP/1.1"); 
client.println("Host: api.strike.acinq.co");
client.println("Authorization: Basic "+apiKey);
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.println(PostData.length());
client.println(); // blank line required
client.println(PostData);

Serial.println("POSTED DATA: " + PostData);
// client.stop();

client.println(); 
} else { 
Serial.println("unable to connect"); 
} 

delay(1000); 
 String line = ""; 
 while (client.connected()) { 
 line = client.readStringUntil('999'); 
 Serial.println(line); 
 Serial.println("parsingValues"); 
 //create a json buffer where to store the json data 
 StaticJsonBuffer<5000> jsonBuffer; 
 JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(line); 
 if (!root.success()) { 
   Serial.println("parseObject() failed"); 
   return; 
 } 
 //get the data from the json tree 
 String nextWeatherTime0 = root["id"][0];
 // Print values. 
 Serial.println(nextWeatherTime0); 

 } 
 client.println("Connection: close"); 
 client.stop();
 }
```

[image: compiled]

Comment: that API doesn't look very secure if it accepts plain unencrypted HTTP connections.. (and your example imply that they do accept plain http without httpS)

Answer (score 0):

Check the response for a BAD request, We usually get it when we deal with a bad URL or URL not found. check whether you are connecting to the same url mentioned in docs.
First connect to the api and after that make queries like providing your api key and feilds 
remove this.

```
 client.println("Host: api.strike.acinq.co");
```

and use GET request to get the response of the data you have in these fields

```
 String PostData = "&description=\"car\"&amount=1000&currency=\"sweetsandthat\""
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also been struggling to get an https post to work on the esp32. A few things, the wifi.h module, I believe, does not support https. The WiFiClientSecure.h does, and you need to set the port to 443. I have also failed to get a POST to work, but I succeed in a basic GET test connection to howsmysssl.com.  Andreas Spiess covers this well in a youtube video. He goes beyond SSL to establishing trust. I just want basic SSL to work, so if you get this figured out, please let me know. Hopefully I got you one step closer. :)